# How to inherit a class within a folder in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a 2 files in my controller and here is the folder list

```
-controller (folder)
 - AbstractTestCase.php
 - PatientControllerTest.php
```

In my AbstractWebtestCase.php

```
namespace AdminBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

abstract class AbstractTestCase extends WebTestCase{}
```

In my PatientControllerTest.php

```
use AdminBundle\Tests\Controller\AbstractTestCase;

class PatientControllerTest extends AbstractTestCase {}
```

I inherit the AbstractTestCase in SpecializationControllerTest when the time I run phpunit I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AdminBundle\Tests\Controller\AbstractTestCase' not found in /Users/helloworld/Projects/sample/src/AdminBundle/Tests/Contoller/PatientControllerTest.php on line 11
```

Why is it I can't inherit it? but when I separate it to other it works.

Comment: The autoloader will be looking for `AbstractTestCase.php` but your file is named `AbstractWebtestCase.php`

Comment: Also, assuming `PatientControllerTest` is in the same namespace as `AbstractTestCase`, you don't need a `use` statement to import the symbol

Comment: @Phil still the same output when I rename AbstractTestCase. even I did add use statement

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: Have you configured an auto-loader? You typically include the composer `autoload.php` in your PHPUnit *bootstrap* file

Answer (score 1):

in you error message there is '.../Tests/Contoller/PatientControllerTest.php', 'Contoller' is missing a 'r'. Is the namespace of this file ok ?

Please be more precise too, ex is your folder 'controller' or maybe 'Controller' and post the whole code instead of parts.